# Delphi: compare properties between two components

Tags: delphi, components

I'd like to compare the "state" of two components, say `Comp1: TSomeComponent` and `Comp2: TSomeComponent`, i.e. I want to compare the values of all the published properties of the two components. Some of the properties are indexed, like the TListBox.Items property. Is there an easy way to do this? Do I have to invoke some iterating RTTI code?

Comment: Delphi 2010 introduced a new and enhanced RTTI far beyond what was possible before. So it's important to know what Delphi version you are currently using to answer propery.

Comment: Alas, I'm using D2009. But: I'll be moving to D2010 sometime in the future anyways, so this could be the nudge I need to convert. Is this possible in D2010?

Comment: Since you only care about `published`, you can do this with RTTI in any version of Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to serialize them both with `WriteComponent` and compare the resulting strings. Note, however, that this would compare only `published`, not `public`, properties. But that is what you say you need, so...

Note that this would make, say, the *order* of the indexed properties significant. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I was actually considering that. What I didn't write in my original question was that I wanted to compare the properties before I (in the case of differences) wrote the properties using WriteComponent. AFAIU you can't single out certain properties to be written using WriteComponent. Is this true? (For the moment, all I care about are the published props...)

Comment: Actually, you can fiddle what properties get written. Take a look at `TComponent.DefineProperties` and related methods/components. This was many years ago, but I've both suppressed properties and added properties not declared as published.

Comment: Craig, you can do that within the component, but not from the code calling the serialization.

Comment: @Craig: Correct; one would have to modify/subclass the components to do this, but it can be done ;) Although, that said; it's a bad reason to subclass a component. So if the requirement is to compare only specific published properties, then RTTI is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no simple compare function in Delphi as far as I know. (I've stopped at D2007.) You could add a method "Compare" to the base class and build the comparison of all fields inside this method. (It should accept one parameter of the same base class.) With D2007 you could build this as a helper class, but you still need to specify the fields.
Other classes could be inherited from this base class and override the base Compare method.

The use of RTTI will make it easier to compare fields of classes from different types but it's complex and error-prone. It will require a lot of testing with all kinds of different classes.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I use (but I would like to have something like this integrated in the IDE) is to copy the dfm part related to the 2 components (using ALT+F12) to access dfm and then I paste the 2 components in [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and I use the Compare Plugin to compare the 2.
It gives a nice visual output, but this takes more time than selecting more components in the IDE (even from different windows) and then Compare them with a compare tool built in in the IDE.